# css horizontal text cutting

Tags: css, height, responsive

I have two responsive divs, one with image and one with text, both are 66,6% height of their width. But i need to cut text clean, so there will not be like half of the row. Is this possible to do with pure css, evetually with js?

[here is what I dont want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGzbm.jpg)

my code:

```css
.head_news {
 width: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
}

.head_news .image {
 width: 45%;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 5%;
}

.head_news .image .auto_height {
 height: 0px;
 padding-bottom: calc(100% / 1.5);
 overflow:hidden;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 50% 50%; 
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s;
    transition: opacity 0.25s;
}

.head_news .text {
 width: 45%;
 float: left;
}

.head_news .text .auto_height {
 height: 0px;
 padding-bottom: calc(100% / 1.5 - 2%);
 overflow:hidden;
 font-size: 14pt;
}

.head_news .text .auto_height h2 {
 font-size: 18pt;
}
```

```html
<div class='head_news'>
   <div class='image'>
    <div class='auto_height' style='background-image: url(http://random-international.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/RR-home-img2.jpg);'></div>
   </div>
   <div class='text'>
      <div class='auto_height'>
      <h2>
     Some random title of unknown lenght
   </h2>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Vestibulum erat nulla, ullamcorper nec, rutrum non, nonummy ac, erat. Etiam dui sem, fermentum vitae, sagittis id, malesuada in, quam. Nulla pulvinar eleifend sem. Fusce tellus odio, dapibus id fermentum quis, suscipit id erat. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Nullam rhoncus aliquam metus. Nullam lectus justo, vulputate eget mollis sed, tempor sed magna. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla quis diam. Curabitur vitae diam non enim vestibulum interdum. Pellentesque arcu. Nulla quis diam. Duis viverra diam non justo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean placerat. Sed vel lectus. Donec odio tempus molestie, porttitor ut, iaculis quis, sem.
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by cut the text clean. can you add a screenshot of the desired behaviour?

Comment: @kittyCat I added example of what i dont want

Comment: Check the post. I think it'll help you. [check it out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220812/css-can-you-prevent-overflow-hidden-from-cutting-off-the-last-line-of-text)

Comment: @Nimish that is what i want, thank you!

Comment: @Nimish unfortunately, this didn't work for me, because it need actual height, but I'm using padding-bottom for automatic height of div

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple css

```
overflow:scroll;
```

or simply match the font size.

Comment: I want to cut text, not scroll, also I can't match font size, because site is responsive.